# Change button's text with jQuery (prev/next)

Tags: jquery

I'm fading in a few panels with a click event. The idea is to change the button's text according to which stage the user is at. If it's a previous panel (not the current one nor the last one) I'd like my button to say: Edit.

Here is what I've done so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/noemitotos/rspj3d66/1/

```
$('.sell-form-wrap').find('.form-panel:not(.current-panel)').hide();

$('.sell-form-wrap').on('click', '.next-button', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  if (!$('.current-panel').hasClass('last-panel')) {
    $('.current-panel').fadeIn(function() {
      $(this).next('.form-panel').addClass('current-panel').fadeIn(function() {
        if ($('.first-panel').is(':visible')) {
          $('.back-button').fadeOut('fast');
        } else {
          $('.back-button').fadeIn('fast');
        }
        if ($('.last-panel').is(':visible')) {
          $('.next-button').find('.button-text').text('Submit');
        } else {
          $('.next-button').find('.button-text').text('Continue');
        }
      });
    })
  } else {
    $('.next-button').find('.button-text').text('Edit');
  }
});
```

Comment: Your JSFiddle contains Html only

Comment: i's updated now!

Comment: can you be more specific on when you want the buttons to change ?

Comment: @NoemiTotos so what is the exact issue you are facing ?

Comment: something like https://jsfiddle.net/rspj3d66/2/ ?

Comment: thanks @link2pk, this is exactly what I want. What a simple solution, beautiful!